# Parameterized Report, reading and creating multiple outputs from a path

Tags: r, r-markdown

For a given path that I want to manually input later, I want R to make as many reports as `.csv` files there are in that directory.

````
---
output: html_document
params:
  directory:
    value: x
---

```{r, echo = F}
csvs <- list.files(params$directory, pattern = "\\.csv$")
done <- list.files(params$directory, pattern = "analysis_")

name_csv <- substr(csvs, 1, nchar(csvs)-4) # .csv
name_done <- substr(done, 19, nchar(done)-5) # .html
selected_csv <- csvs[min(which(!(name_csv %in% name_done )))]

.
.
.
```
````

What I'm trying to do is select which `csv` hasn't been analyzed yet by matching if they have the same text. The `.csv` have unique names, so if I had `unique1.csv`  and `analysis_unique1.html`, the code would skip and go to `unique2.csv`.

This first part already makes my code fail. I get:

> Error in object[seq_len(ile)] : 
>     object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

I tried to remove this part of the code and had the same problem when I was trying to access something from the "outside". For example, my code also breaks when it tries to load a package. Or even later, when I try to do a `read.csv` (I manually wrote the csv name).

````
```{r, echo = F}
data <- read.csv(selected_csv)
```
````

While even a basic `rmarkdown::render("file.Rmd")` doesn't work, the full render I'm trying to do is:

```
for(i in 1:length(list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$"))){
  rmarkdown::render( 
  input="file.Rmd", 
  output_file= paste('analysis_', substr(
  list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")[i], 1, nchar(selected_csv)-4), sep = ' '), 
  params = "ask") 
}
```

Although I'm not sure the `nchar(selected_csv)` part would work, as it's referencing the `Rmdfile`.

Anyway that was my lame attempt in doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve.

The code snippet below will list down every csv file, check if html file exists, if not, render the html file

```
lapply(list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$"), function(x) {
    outhtml <- paste0("analysis_",basename(x),".html")
    if (!file.exists(outhtml)) {
        rmarkdown::render("file.Rmd", "html_document", outhtml)
    }
})
```

HTH

Comment: This is great, it's almost working right now. The only problem i have is that i have to input the directory every time. Since it keeps opening the "ask" screen. Any solution to that?

Comment: remove the `params` argument input

Comment: But i actually want to input it the first time. Should i just put something like `params = list( directory = path)` and previously just input the path manually in R?

Comment: y dont you add a dirpath variable so that it will be used subsequently?